# Filter a data-set from a dictionary keys and values

Tags: python, pandas

let's say I have a `pd.DataFrame` :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Press':['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
                   'Model':[1, 2 ,2 , 2, 1],
                   'Count':[1, 1 ,1 , 1, 1]})
```

After sorting, I only want to keep data matching `somedict = {'A':2, 'B':2}`. (keys=Press, values=Model)

Is there an easy way to only keep indexes `[1,2,3]` ?

Comment: Can you post what you are seeing and what you would like to see instead?  Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go using `merge`

```
s=pd.Series(somedict).to_frame('Model').rename_axis('Press').reset_index()
yourdf=df.merge(s)
Out[231]: 
  Press  Model  Count
0     B      2      1
1     B      2      1
2     A      2      1
```

Comment: If the result should really be a dict one could add s.th. like: `somedict = pd.Series(yourdf.Model.values,index= yourdf.Press).to_dict()` right?

Comment: @skymon yes, you can adding dict

Comment: Much better than my solution: `keys = [k + ' - ' + str(v) for k,v in somedict.items()]` then `df['key'] = df['Press'] + ' - ' + df['Model'].apply(lambda x:str(x))` and finally `df[df['key'].isin(keys)]`

Answer (score 2):

here is another way using `map` and `query`:

```
df.assign(match=df.Press.map(somedict)).query('Model==match').drop('match',1)
```

---

```
  Press  Model  Count
0     B      2      1
1     A      2      1
2     B      2      1
```

Comment: I like `map` and `query`. It looks clean and nice :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using `agg` columns `Press` and `Model` to series of tuples and use `isin` on `somedict.items()` to create the mask with and `.loc` to slice the desired rows

```
m = df[['Press', 'Model']].agg(tuple, axis=1).isin(somedict.items())
df.loc[m]

Out[785]:
  Press  Model  Count
1  B     2      1
2  A     2      1
3  B     2      1
```